# Raster Calculator - Clip RGB by Raster

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am using the Gdal-Raster Calculator in QGIS to clip a Input-Raster (3-Bands RGB (A,B,C)) by another Raster (D) (containing 0/1-Values) by using the expression (A*D)+(B*D)+(C*D), which works well. However the Output contains only one single Band (grey1).

Is there a possibility to get an output with all three input Bands again?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I noticed there is an "--allBands" Option.